# iplimage to mat 32 bit conversion error

Tags: opencv

I want to convert an iplimage to a cv::mat (not CvMat). With this code the values themes to be overflowed...

```
IplImage mhi32f = cvCreateImage(cvSize(draw_rect.width,draw_rect.height), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
cv::Mat mhi32_mat(mhi32f);
mhi32_mat.convertTo(mhi32_mat,CV_32FC1);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as explained [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/c++_cheatsheet.html), you just have to do that

```
Mat imgMat(iplimg);  //Construct an Mat image "img" out of an IplImage
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, `IplImage mhi32f = ...` should be `IplImage* mhi32f = ...`, but I'll assume that was a typo on your part.

Your example is fine except that you don't need the `convertTo` call. If you want to copy the `IplImage` data to the `Mat` object simply pass `true` as the second argument to the constructor as shown [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat%3a%3amat#Mat%3a%3aMat%28const%20IplImage%2a%20img,%20bool%20copyData%29).

Here is an example showing that the type is already `CV_32FC1`:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* mhi32f = cvCreateImage(cvSize(320, 240), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
    cv::Mat mhi32_mat(mhi32f);

    assert(mhi32_mat.type() == CV_32FC1);

    cout << "Already a CV_32FC1 matrix..." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.